# Conversion from initializer_list<const char*> to initializer_list<string> in vector constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, stdinitializerlist, braced-init-list

`std::vector`‘s initializer list constructor has the form

```cpp
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

What makes an initialization like `std::vector<string> vec{ “foo”, “bar” };` possible? Why does the constructor accept an `std::initializer_list<const char*>`, even though the `std::vectors`‘s `T` is `std::string`? Where and how does the conversion from `std::initializer_list<const char*>`to `std::initializer_list<string>` happen?

Comment: Here's a way to solve this Smystery, all by yourself, and actually have a very beneficial learning experience: write this code, use your debugger to step into the vector's constructor, see which constructor gets called, and how exactly it goes about doing what it does. This is one of those questions that nobody needs to ask, since they can easily find the answer themselves using only a tool that every C++ developer must know how to use: a debugger. Did you try doing it? What did your debugger show you, as far as which constructor gets used for this?

Comment: I agree, but just in case you are using Visual Studio's debugger you will have to turn off the 'Just My Code' feature to do this. I believe it's on by default, and useful most of the time, but not here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Let's be fair, the debugger doesn't show anything here. My GDB just shows three `std::string(const char *)` constructors being called, and without knowing the theory, one can't tell if this is an `initializer_list<const char *>` being converted to an `initializer_list<string>`, or `initializer_list<string>` being constructed element-wise from pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should refer to this section of the C++ 17 Standard (11.6.4 List-initialization)

> 5 An object of type std::initializer_list is constructed from an
> initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized
> (7.4) a prvalue of type “array of N const E”, where N is the number of
> elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is
> copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer
> list, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer
> to that array. [ **Note: A constructor or conversion function selected
> for the copy shall be accessible (Clause 14) in the context of the
> initializer list. — end note ]** If a narrowing conversion is required
> to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed. [
> Example:

```
struct X {
X(std::initializer_list<double> v);
};
X x{ 1,2,3 };
```

> The initialization will be implemented in a way roughly equivalent to
> this:

```
const double __a[3] = {double{1}, double{2}, double{3}};
X x(std::initializer_list<double>(__a, __a+3));
```

> assuming that the implementation can construct an initializer_list
> object with a pair of pointers. — end example ]

Pay attention to that there is the conversion constructor for the class `std::basic_string`

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

So in this declaration

```
std::vector<string> vec{ “foo”, “bar” };
```

at first an object of the type `std::initializer_list<std::string>` is constructed from the initializer list and then is used as an initializer for the vector of the type `std::vector<std::string>`.

If instead you will write

```
std::initializer_list<const char *> lst = { "foo", "bar" };
std::vector<std::string> vec( lst );
```

then the compiler will issue an error because there is no implicit conversion from the type `std::initializer_list<const char *>` to the type `std::initializer_list<std::string>`.

That is the compiler determines whether it can build `std::initializer_list` from a braced initializer list to call the initializer-list constructor.